# Error 404 Not Found on POST request with my Spring Boot CRUD login & registration app on Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, crud, registration

I made a user login & registration app on spring boot, it runs successfully without any error but displays the error "404 Not Found" when I do a POST request on POSTMAN. Why is it so, sharing my code below-

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.guides.springboot3</groupId>
    <artifactId>Backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Backend</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Backend</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

RegistrationController.java

```
package net.guides.springboot3.Backend.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


//import net.guides.springboot3.Backend.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import net.guides.springboot3.Backend.model.User;
import net.guides.springboot3.Backend.repository.UserRepository;
import net.guides.springboot3.Backend.service.UserService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RegistrationController {

    private UserService userService;

    public RegistrationController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        boolean isRegistered = userService.registerUser(user);
        if (!isRegistered) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Email already in use", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User registered successfully. Verify your email before login", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //verifyEmail endpoint method
    @GetMapping("/verify-email")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> verifyEmail(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        boolean isVerified = userService.verifyEmail(token);
        if (!isVerified) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Invalid token", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Email verified successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java:

```
package net.guides.springboot3.Backend.repository;


import net.guides.springboot3.Backend.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    boolean existsByEmail(String email);
    User findByVerificationToken(String token);
}
```

User.java:

```
package net.guides.springboot3.Backend.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    private String verificationToken;
    // other fields

    // getters and setters
    public String getVerificationToken() {
        return verificationToken;
    }

    // getters and setters
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Column(name = "verification_token")
    public void setVerificationToken(String verificationToken) {
        this.verificationToken = verificationToken;
    }

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "is_verified", nullable = false)
    private boolean isVerified;
    // getters and setters
    public void setIsVerified(boolean isVerified) {
        this.isVerified = isVerified;
    }

    public boolean getIsVerified() {
        return isVerified;
    }

    // getters and setters
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

UserService.java:

```
package net.guides.springboot3.Backend.service;

import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import net.guides.springboot3.Backend.model.User;
import net.guides.springboot3.Backend.repository.UserRepository;

import net.guides.springboot3.Backend.model.User;
import net.guides.springboot3.Backend.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
        this.passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public boolean registerUser(User user) {
        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())) {
            return false;
        }
        //Encrypt password using bcrypt
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setVerificationToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        user.setIsVerified(false);
        userRepository.save(user);

        // send verification email
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mailMessage.setTo(user.getEmail());
        mailMessage.setSubject("Verify your email address");
        mailMessage.setText("Please click the link below to verify your email address: \n"
                + "http://localhost:8080/verify-email?token=" + user.getVerificationToken());
        javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean verifyEmail(String token) {
        User user = userRepository.findByVerificationToken(token);
        if (user == null) {
            return false;
        }
        user.setIsVerified(true);
        user.setVerificationToken(null);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Sharing the POSTMAN screen snap:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjR1C.png)

Comment: check for any context path in application.yml

Comment: are there any messages in the server console log?

Comment: @RyuzakiL Thanks for ur hint, I had added a context path which I hadn't mentioned in the POSTMAN request; removed that path, but **got other error now**, it says: 

o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
Column 'first_name' cannot be null
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]] with root cause

Postman also mentions: 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because of adding a context path in application.properties, due to which postman was unable to find my application at 'http://localhost:8080/'.

The context path I added was: "server.servlet.context-path=/springboot-crud-rest" ; hence my application was running at 'http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest' & the url for POST request would be 'http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/register'.

To resolve this, either append the url by adding context path as above or remove the context path from application.properties & use the earlier url only.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your code is good but I am not sure that your POSTMAN request parameters.

To see if i'm right, you should add a breakpoint in your method `registerUser()` in youre `RegistrationController`  just to see if the breakpoint is triggered when you call this entrypoint via POSTMAN. If the breackpoint is not triggered, it means that you didn't write your POSTMAN request well

Comment: you could leave this comment on the post it self